# ¿Cómo podría hacer para que mi resultado me arroje en decimales?

Tags: php, mysql

Trataré de explicarme lo mejor posible:

En esta simple operación, que se realiza dentro de mi formulario:

```
$p_compra=$_POST["p_compra"];

$a=1;
$b=.6;
$p_venta= ($p_compra/$a) * $b + $p_compra;
```

En el valor de $b, al poner yo .66, me arroja el valor de 0 en mi precio de venta, cuando se ejecuta la fórmula, puesto no acepta los decimales (no ejecuta el valor, puesto que lleva dos decimales [.66], ya que al poner [.6] me arroja un valor cercano, pero no el que necesito).

La operación es funcional. Busco el tipo dato o formato que me permita imprimir mi resultado ya sea con [.] y/o [decimales].

Actualmente utilizó [número] y está me brinda el resultado en [enteros].

Comment: Diria que falta información para reproducir tu error. Tal como lo has puesto en la pregunta funciona bien, al menos en PHP. Si te da 0 será porque el $_POST que recibes es 0, no veo otro motivo.  Por otra parte, esta parte de la fórmula no tiene sentido:  `$p_compra/$a` puesto que `$a=1` y todo número dividido por 1 es el mismo número. No se entiende que pretendes con ello tampoco.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Una disculpa más bien, más bien busco la variable que me pueda arrojar el valor en decimales, actualmente utilizo número y este no me permite valores en decimales y busco que me permita punto (.) y decimales.

Comment: Lo que has puesto en la pregunta es solo PHP, no has indicado que el problema sea al mostrarlo en el HTML con un input de tipo `number` como me parece adivinar a través del enlace que has puesto en la respuesta.  Cuando dices "imprimir" el resultado sin más datos habia entendido que al hacer un `echo $p_venta` no te salian decimales, lo cual no era cierto pues a mi si me salian.  Debes especificar mejor lo que pides cuando preguntas si realmente quieres buenas respuestas, porque era ambigua y no has puesto el HTML de salida al cual te referias. Me alegro que ya lo hayas solucionado. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias masterguro

Answer (score -1):

Eh encontrado una página que me está ayudando para obtener el resultado como lo quiero.

Una de las características de HTML5 era que permitía definir campos de tipos variados que ampliaban las opciones respecto al tradicional tipo text del HTML clásico.  Estos campos, además tienen la capacidad de autovalidarse.

Estos nuevos campos, por otra parte, requieren conocer todas sus opciones para exprimirlos a tope. Por ejemplo, si declaras un campo como el siguiente:

En este caso te encontrarás con que si pones un número decimal la validación del navegador te dirá que está incorrecto. Pero tú sabes que no lo está ¿por qué pasa esto? Bueno, puedes arreglarlo de una forma muy simple: con el atributo step.

La mayoría de los navegadores mostrarán dos flechas en los campos de tipo number, para aumentar y decrecentar su valor. En step podemos definir cuánto queremos que este valor suba o baje en cada click. Por ejemplo:

De esa form el valor irá cambiando de 5 en 5.

Pero esto de momento no nos soluciona el problema ¿cómo logramos que trague un decimal? Pues definiendo en step que el valor sea decimal.Si ponemos el valor de step como «0.01» nos permitirá meter decimales con dos cifras. Entonces si ponemos nuestro campo:

Así tenemos un campo que admite dos cifras decimales, que suele ser lo más habitual. Si queremos más precisión entonces metemos más decimales en el step. Otra opción es añadir directamente el valor any a step. De esta forma permitirá meter tantos decimales como queramos.

La información es del siguiente enlace:
https://donnierock.com/2016/04/20/html5-lograr-que-un-campo-number-acepte-decimales/amp/

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Veronica, me alegra que encontrases una página que te sirve de ayuda. Por favor, edita la respuesta para añadir las partes clave de la página en la propia publicación, porque tal y como está redactada ahora, la respuesta se considera de baja calidad (si el enlace se rompe, deja de tener sentido). Lee [answer] para más información.